# Missing dependency: ionic-angular when trying to use ionic-stepper

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, stepper

I want to use [`ionic-stepper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-stepper) in my project.

I downloaded this package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-stepper. When I use it, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "ionic-stepper" has missing dependencies:
[ng]  - ionic-angular
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You're missing `ionic-angular`:

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "ionic-stepper" has missing dependencies:
[ng]  - ionic-angular
```

`ionic-angular` [is listed as a dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-stepper#prerequisites), so you'll need to get a copy if you want to use `ionic-stepper`.

Here is the cause of your problem:

> I downloaded this package...

Manually downloading files isn't the recommended way to install libraries from NPM.

Instead, use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) or [the NPM CLI tool](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6) to install it. These tools will automatically identify and install dependent packages, like `ionic-angular`:

```
yarn add ionic-stepper
```